# Limit Wordpress login to certain ip-addresses on Nginx and PHP-FPM

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, wordpress, brute-force-attacks

I've seen a lot of bruce force attacks on Wordpress, so I want to limit access to wp-login.php.
It's the latest Wordpress on a Ubuntu 16.04LTS Nginx server with PHP-FPM.

I've tried the advice from the [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Brute_Force_Attacks):

```
location /wp-admin {
  allow   x.x.x.x;
  deny    all;
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work. It only blocks /wp-admin, but allows /wp-admin/index.php

Comment: There are many articles about Nginx around, this one is something you should read if you're going to use it: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms

Answer (score 0):

Block it recursive beginning with the /wp-admin directory

```
location ^~ /wp-admin {
  allow x.x.x.x;
  deny all;
}
```